# Убрать из url .php

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

есть код `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ $1.php [NC]
```

Он позволяет обращаться к страницам не дописывая расширения файла `.php`

нужна еще строка , которая будет скрывать расширение `.php` из `url` если пользователь введет `example.com/about.php`
также есть много ссылок которые ведут к `example.com/about.php` , ссылки менять не вариант , поэтому нужна строка которая будет скрывать расширение в url , если оно там есть.

Comment: Я обычно перенаправляю все запросы на index.php, а тот, в свою очередь, создает роутер и подгружает нужные контроллеры.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том что .htaccess не может изменять url. Можно лишь сделать редирект со страниц с расширением .php на страницы без .php

Comment: вот этот код убирает расширение .php с каждой страницы , только он конфликтует с функцией header поэтому я ищу аналог                  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ $0.php [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ([^\s]*)\.php(\?[^\s]*)?
RewriteRule (.*) %1 [R=301,L]